# Spring boot, Autowire Mongo repo generates BeanCreationException

Tags: spring, mongodb, maven, spring-boot, autowired

I read several similar questions and answers related to `autowire` and `BeanCreationException` and it seems that the main source of problem is usually in `ComponentScan` annotation and the project tree.

But I still can't understand why my application throws this exception.
Here is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test.game</groupId>
    <artifactId>gameP</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2-beta</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The application runner with the `SpringBootApplication` annotation

```
package core.main.exec;

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("core.main")
public class ApplicationRunner implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    GameEntityRepository repo;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(ApplicationRunner.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Game newGame = new Game();
        newGame.setId(1213123L);
        newGame.setName("halo 123");
        newGame.setDeck("Duck");
        newGame.setMedium_url("url");
        repo.save(newGame);
    }
}
```

And the repository is defined as bellow

```
package core.main.controller;

public interface GameEntityRepository extends MongoRepository {
}
```

And the Mongo entity named `Game` is as bellow

```
package core.main.mongoentity;

@Document
public class Game {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String deck;
    private String name;
    private String medium_url;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDeck() {
        return deck;
    }

    public void setDeck(String deck) {
        this.deck = deck;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getMedium_url() {
        return medium_url;
    }

    public void setMedium_url(String medium_url) {
        this.medium_url = medium_url;
    }
}
```

As soon as I run the application I get a `BeanCreationException` with the following error message

> Could not autowire field: core.main.controller.GameEntityRepository core.main.exec.ApplicationRunner.repo

Answer (score 0):

I think this error caused by package scanning

refactor this

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("core.main")
public class ApplicationRunner implements CommandLineRunner {}
```

like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan({"core.main.mongoentity"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"core.main.controller"})
public class ApplicationRunner implements CommandLineRunner {}
```

and also dont use `@ComponentScan("core.main")` because `@SpringBootApplication` provides  the attributes of `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan`

and also your repository incorrect you dont declare entity for `MongoRepository`

refactor your repository

```
public interface GameEntityRepository extends MongoRepository {}
```

like this

```
public interface GameEntityRepository extends MongoRepository<Game,Long>{}
```

and add this dependency in pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you added the @EnableJpaRepositories annotation. But just adding the entity scan will give me a new error which says Error creating bean with name 'embeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor'.

Comment: this tomcat error your now your beans created successful

Comment: There is no tomcat dependency in the pom. maybe I'm missing something there?!

Comment: make project clean and bulid and and also reimport maven dependency

Comment: I added the scope as compiler to the dependency of spring-boot-starter-web but it did not help. still getting the same error. Also I think if you want to have a customized ComponentScan, you can do it even if you have the annotation of SpringBootApplication.

Comment: @Salman9 you get embeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor error  again

Comment: @Salman9 I edit my answer add this depencency and bulid your project